# How to detect web page language with no lang attribute

Tags: javascript, localization

I have an extension and need to detect the language of webpage. I learned I can obtain "lang" to get the answer. However, lots of webpage don't have "lang" attribute in .
In this case, how can I know what language of the webpage is?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The language is set by the user's browser in the navigator object's language property. [Here's an explanation from W3Schools.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_language.asp)

```
var lang = navigator.language;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, what I need is not browser default language. What I want to know is the language of webpage which users are viewing.

Comment: What does your extension do? Is it a translator?

Comment: My extension will help a user search the address when she provide name of a place. Google Places API will response address by language based on language code.